# mod_rewrite - check for string

Tags: string, mod-rewrite, rule

I want to check if a URL contains the sting "-EN.htm", if so apply the rewrite.

That should be done with ^-EN.htm as follows, but the rule is not working:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/([-_0-9a-zA-Z./=]*)^-EN.htm
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /indexEN.php?folder=%1&follow=%2 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for every help,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't look right. You can also lose the condition and just move the pattern to the rewrite rule instead. Something along the lines of

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/([-_0-9a-zA-Z./=]*)^-EN.htm /indexEN.php?folder=$1&follow=$2 [L]
```

You need to make the leading slash optional (in htaccess this is stripped off) and instead of using **%** backreferences, use the **$** ones.

Now on to your pattern, it's not valid. The `^` matches the beginning of the string (the URI), so if you have two of them and you're not trying to literally match the `^` character (which you'd need to escape), then the expression will never match anything. Without any examples of URLs that you're having to deal with, I assume you probably just want to ditch the second `^`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/([-_0-9a-zA-Z./=]*)-EN.htm /indexEN.php?folder=$1&follow=$2 [L]
```